# Moonsharp pairs(...) raises exception "bad argument #1 to 'next' (table expected, got string)"

Tags: c#, lua, moonsharp

I don't get the point why this is happening.
I am using Moonsharp to run LUA scripts in my application an I created a LUA function IN(v, ...) and I'd like to itterate over the ... parameter with pairs.

```
IN('param1', 'param2', 'param1') -- expected it to return true
function IN(v, ...)
    local args = ...
    local res = true
    for i, v in pairs(args) do
        if valueIn == v then
            res = true
            break
        end
    end
    return res
end
```

If it gets called I recieve the folowing exception:

> "MoonSharp.Interpreter.ScriptRuntimeException"
>   bad argument #1 to 'next' (table expected, got string)

So I decided to check if there is a string instead of a Table in my ... variable.

```
function args(v, ...)
    return ...
end
```

The return value in C# is a Tuple of 2 values with 'param2' and 'param1', so it should work with pairs or ipairs, shouldn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pairs` operates on a table, perhaps you meant `local args = {...}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this definition like in your example:

```
function test(...)
  local arg = ...
end
```

and calling

```
test(1,2,3)
```

will result in

```
local arg = 1, 2, 3
```

which of course only assigns 1 to arg. The rest is omitted.

But as the table constructor takes `...` as input you may write

`local arg = {...}` or and then happily iterate over your new table arg.
`...` is not a table as lua just told you. Hence you cannot iterate over `...`

Alternatively local `arg = table.pack(...)` will also work.

The vararg system has been changed in Lua 5.1, in case you're curious
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.1

> The vararg system changed from the pseudo-argument arg with a table
>   with the extra arguments to the vararg expression. (See compile-time
>   option LUA_COMPAT_VARARG in luaconf.h.)

Befor you could do something like

```
function test(...)

  for k,v in pairs(arg) do
    print("I'm a generic for loop yeah!!!")
  end

end
```

So the `local arg = {...}` was not necessary.

Comment: Just for fully understanding the point. What kind of object is ... by itself, if it is no table?

Comment: @georgpoweleit its an expression that evaluates to a list of values. similar to a function call that returns multiple values.  maybe this is worth a read: http://lua-users.org/wiki/VarargTheSecondClassCitizen