# Looping a C# dictionary in Lua with MoonSharp

Tags: c#, lua, moonsharp

I would like to iterate through something like this:

```
public readonly IDictionary<int, Entity> Entities = new Dictionary<int, Entity>();
```

In Lua, whilst using MoonSharp. From the docs, it appears that MoonSharp handles automatic conversion to a table for `IDictionary` types?

However, trying to do something like this ...

```
for k,v in pairs(World.Entities) do
  -- something
end
```

... is giving me:

`ScriptRuntimeException: bad argument #1 to 'next' (table expected, got userdata)`

Is there something I'm missing as to why MoonSharp isn't converting my dictionary into a table?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems relevant or duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218769/moonsharp-pairs-raises-exception-bad-argument-1-to-next-table-expected

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why MoonSharp isn't automatically handling this - at first I assumed it may have been a problem with my 'Entity' type, but I've switched that out and tested around it, and still nothing.

My workaround for now is to handle the conversion inside my .lua files.

```
function convert.dictTable(clr)
  local table = {}
  local enumerator = clr:GetEnumerator()

  while enumerator:MoveNext() do
    table[enumerator.Current.Key] = enumerator.Current.Value
  end

  return table
end
```